# Facebook's 'like button' doesn't work as it should

Tags: facebook-like

I know there are many threads on this subject; I read them all (I think) and none of them is an answer to my problem, so here goes:
I want a facebook 'like' button om my website; the kind which invites the liker to add a comment. It is working 'a bit', but not the way I'd expect. I use a special fb-account for testing and found that:

- The fact that I 'liked' my webpage shows up under 'actions', but NOT under 'likes'.
- The 'comment' gets lost (is not published). Consequently, the 'like doesn't show up in the timeline. (From FB's documentation, I gather that 'likes' are published on the timeline only if a comment was added. And indeed, it seems to work that way when I click the like-button on other websites and add a comment.) Consequently, it doesn't show up on the 'newsfeed' of my 'friends' either.

What did I do wrong?

- Of course I used the FB debugger (the 'linter') to make sure my webpage passed all tests.
- I used the iFrame version as well as the javascript version of the button, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.
- I used the code as generated by fb's own code-generator (that is the xdbml-version using javascript), as well as iFrame code from other code-generators. Finally, I copied the exact iFrame-code from another website, which DOES exactly work as expected (that is: the like action shows up in the timeline with the provided comment and the 'like is added to my set of 'likes'.) I just replaced the URL with my own, taking care it is properly url-encoded. But this code, while clearly working for someone else, is not working for me: I get the same disappointing result.

There is, in fact, another difference still: when, in facebook, I click on the link of some other website I 'liked' I am immediately taken to that website and the page I 'liked'. But when I click on the link to my wn website, I first get a 'warning' dialogue-box, informing me of the dangers of clicking links.  For the life of me I can't understand why these differences in behaviour occcurr.

A hint that something is wrong may be (?) that on my website, when the 'comment-box' appears after clicking the button, it doesn't close when I click 'publish'; instead the box stays visible until I click 'close'.
Here is the code I use:

Meta-tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Modern soefisme - Modern Sufism" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Home Page of Mabel van Asperen, devoted to sufism,  sufi acivities and sufi literature" />
<meta property="og:type" content="non_profit" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.phlogiston.nl/speeltuin/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.phlogiston.nl/speeltuin/images/hearts_with_wings.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sufi Stuff" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000985117039" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

The iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ephlogiston%2Enl%2Fspeeltuin%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The xfbml-version:

```
<script Language="javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.phlogiston.nl/speeltuin/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? I would be most grateful, as I'm getting rather frustrated since 'everybody' seems to be able to make a well-functioning like-button but I can't. (And I'm also getting tired of the fact that 'experimenting' seems to be so difficult: after clicking the like-button once I can't use it again. So, for each try I have to make up a new webpage. Or does someone know a better way?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this will solve your problem but try changing the overflow css value in the iframe to something other than hidden.

The [facebook reference for the like plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) states:

> When I click the Like button, the popup window (or "flyout") doesn't
>   show. Why?
>
> If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the
>   overflow property set  to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or
>   completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by
>   setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden, such as
>   visible, scroll, or auto.

As far as 'unliking' your like button, its hard to see but if you move your mouse cursor to the left side of the like button, a grey 'x' will appear.

[image: a grey 'x' will appear.]

Click on that and you will unlike.

Hope that helps!

I'm having a tough time with this too so your not alone!  I can't seem to get the pop up from the like button which allows me to share a link in my feed.  I keep getting this 'Unknown RPC service: widget-interactive' error. Wish it was easier.